# Questions about the differences between a set of packages

Tags: discussion, big-list

For example:

- Pros and Cons of each `\marginpar`, sidenote, scrlayer-notecolumn and other maginalia packages (question I was thinking of answering)
- <s>[Fundamental differences : PSTricks, TikZ/PGF and others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others)</s>
- [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83037/difference-between-ref-varioref-and-cleveref-decision-for-a-thesis)
- <s>[array, table, tabular, tabularx, longtable, supertabular, longtabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214840/5834)</s>
- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/5834)
- [A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package)

I feel like these are interesting questions.
I am constantly like *"Argh, I need a special table, now what was the difference between tabularx and and tabulary. Maybe I should be switching to a cool new table making option..."*

I think these are best when they are written in Big-list form.
With only one package/method per answer.
Of which only the last is.

I don't trust my instincts though for big-list questions though. As they are forbidden on almost every other site.

My questions are:

- Are these good on-topic questions?
- Is it generally agrees that for this kind of question the big-list, one answer per package is the best format?
- Is it reasonable to reask some of the existing questions (listed above) as big-list questions?

Comment: The problem with one option per answer is that the most well-known will end up on top and not the best, e.g. in the beginner's manual question the Wikibook is on top even though Marc van Dongen's LaTeX and friends is *much* better (I reckon).

Comment: If you have the question be community wiki and then post a single answer, People can edit that to list the options. This is more compact and easier to scan than one per answer. Where there are only a few options, it is different, but for tables, say, there are zillions. I think these questions should be community wiki because there are clearly no criteria for picking a 'best' answer. (Is the best answer the one which mentions the best package? Or the one which explains why the most popular package isn't the best one? Or the one which is best for use in Beamer? Or ...?

Comment: The titles need to be done with care. The current title for the `keyval` doesn't make sense: does it mean 'key-value' packages? Or all the competing, conflicting `keyval` packages? Why do you want to reask existing questions? Some of these clearly aren't `big-list` questions e.g. the Biber/Biblatex versus BibTeX/natbib one.

Comment: Small nitpick: The PSTricks, TikZ/PGF and others question is not about the package differences but the engine difference. I specifically tried to get the discussion away from that.